# Java - JWT Token Invalid Signature

Tags: java, authentication, jwt

I have a problem getting my JWT Token verified, despite it giving me the correct payload.

Excuse me if I'm a little insecure in this part of the code, since this was handed out by our teacher via a template, but we are unable to reach him.

We had to make some changes to the code itself, since it had the username put into the token and we want the email put in.

We are using something called UserPrincipal, what I can understand, its used to determine access rights to a file or object and originally we used roles to determine what users had access to which endpoints. This is not the case in this project, since its a short demo based on other features.

How does our user principal class look like?

```
package rest;

import entity.User;

import java.security.Principal;

public class UserPrincipal implements Principal {

    private String name;
    private String email;

    public UserPrincipal(User user) {
        this.email = user.getEmail();
    }

    public UserPrincipal(String email) {
        super();
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return email;
    }

}
```

See, here the user principal used to also get a list of roles and instead of a email, it got a username.

Where do we use this user principal? Well, we use it when we generate our token. This is also here we have our endpoint, yes it should be moved to our interface class.

```
package rest;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSAlgorithm;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSHeader;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSSigner;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.MACSigner;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;
import entity.User;
import facade.UserFacade;
import exceptions.AuthenticationException;
import exceptions.GenericExceptionMapper;
import utils.PuSelector;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Path("login")
public class LoginEndpoint {

    private static final int TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 30; // ms * sec * min = 30 min
    private static final UserFacade USER_FACADE = UserFacade.getInstance(PuSelector.getEntityManagerFactory("pu"));

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response login(String jsonString) throws AuthenticationException {

        JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
        String email = json.get("email").getAsString();
        String password = json.get("password").getAsString();
        String ip = json.get("ip").getAsString();

        try {
            User user = USER_FACADE.getVeryfiedUser(email, password, ip);
            String code = USER_FACADE.sendCode(email);
            String token = createToken(email);

            JsonObject responseJson = new JsonObject();
            responseJson.addProperty("code", code);
            responseJson.addProperty("email", email);
            responseJson.addProperty("token", token);
            return Response.ok(new Gson().toJson(responseJson)).build();
        } catch (JOSEException | AuthenticationException ex) {
            if (ex instanceof AuthenticationException) {
                throw (AuthenticationException) ex;
            }
            Logger.getLogger(GenericExceptionMapper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        throw new AuthenticationException("Somthing went wrong! Please try again");
    }

    private String createToken(String email) throws JOSEException {
        //String firstNameLetter = user.getFirstName().substring(0, 1);
        //String lastNameLetter = user.getLastName().substring(0, 1);
        //int ageTimesID = user.getAge() * user.getId();
        //String name = firstNameLetter + lastNameLetter + ageTimesID;

        String issuer = "the_turtle_troopers";

        JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner(SharedSecret.getSharedKey());
        Date date = new Date();
        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                .subject(email)
                .claim("email", email)
                .claim("allowed", true)
                .claim("issuer", issuer)
                .issueTime(date)
                .expirationTime(new Date(date.getTime() + TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIME))
                .build();
        SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.HS256), claimsSet);
        signedJWT.sign(signer);
        return signedJWT.serialize();
    }
}
```

We have a security context class.. Not quite sure if this has any impact on my problem, but regardless:

```
package rest;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import java.security.Principal;

public class JWTSecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

    UserPrincipal user;
    ContainerRequestContext request;

    public JWTSecurityContext(UserPrincipal user, ContainerRequestContext request) {
        this.user = user;
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return request.getUriInfo().getBaseUri().getScheme().equals("https");
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return "JWT"; //Only for INFO
    }
}
```

And finally we have our JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
package rest;

import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSVerifier;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.MACVerifier;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;
import exceptions.AuthenticationException;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.annotation.security.DenyAll;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final List<Class<? extends Annotation>> securityAnnotations 
            = Arrays.asList(DenyAll.class, PermitAll.class, RolesAllowed.class);
    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        if (isSecuredResource()) {

            String token = request.getHeaderString("x-access-token");//
            if (token == null) {
                request.abortWith(exceptions.GenericExceptionMapper.makeErrRes(token, 403));
                return;
            }
            try {
                UserPrincipal user = getUserPrincipalFromTokenIfValid(token);
                //What if the client had logged out????
                request.setSecurityContext(new JWTSecurityContext(user, request));
            } catch (AuthenticationException | ParseException | JOSEException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                request.abortWith(exceptions.GenericExceptionMapper.makeErrRes("Token not valid (timed out?)", 403));
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isSecuredResource() {
        for (Class<? extends Annotation> securityClass : securityAnnotations) {
            if (resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().isAnnotationPresent(securityClass)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (Class<? extends Annotation> securityClass : securityAnnotations) {
            if (resourceInfo.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(securityClass)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private UserPrincipal getUserPrincipalFromTokenIfValid(String token) throws ParseException, JOSEException, AuthenticationException {
        SignedJWT signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);
        //Is it a valid token (generated with our shared key)
        JWSVerifier verifier = new MACVerifier(SharedSecret.getSharedKey());

        if (signedJWT.verify(verifier)) {
            if (new Date().getTime() > signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime().getTime()) {
                throw new AuthenticationException("Your Token is no longer valid");
            }
            String email = signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getClaim("email").toString();

            return new UserPrincipal(email);
        } else {
            throw new JOSEException("User could not be extracted from token");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone will be able to tell me why it is my token isn't getting validated on jwt.io

[image]

Comment: you didn't provide any secret inthe field under "Verify Signature in the right column, so how could jwt.io verify the sig without knowing the secret.

Comment: The bigger (and more important) question here is whether your Java server, which issued the JWT in the first place, can verify the checksum and validity of the tokens.

Comment: How would one find that secret? @jps

Comment: @dumbprogrammer: sorry, didn't read all your code. Was the token produced by your own code? Then it's the secret you used when signing the token. If the token comes from somewhere else, then the secret might be, well, a secret.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I assumed it was a verification issue, due to not being able to get the users data when subtracting the email from the token on another endpoint.

Comment: regarding the verification on jwt.io: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291731/using-jwt-dotnet-to-generate-a-valid-token

Comment: @jps Yes the token is created by "my" own code.. It seems like no matter what i write into the secret field it validates it?

Comment: jwt.io is a bit tricky to use. In the moment you write something into the field, a new signature is calculated. You can observe the change on the signature part of the token on the left side. To really verify an existing token, you first have to paste the secret into the field in the right coloumn and then paste the token itself into the left column.

Comment: @jps I appreciate the answer, I guess my problem doesn't really stem from having an invalid token, since its no invalid, so I will create another question with the real problem. Have a great day.